# How can I add a Home AppWidget from mainActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have the mainActivity class:

```
....
final Button addWidgetBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addWidget);

addWidgetBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //on button click add Home Widget       

}

});
....
```

The main.xml view:

```
....
<Button android:id="@+id/addWidget" android:text="Add widget"/>
....
```

The FlowerForYouWidget.java class:

```
public class FlowerForYouWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
...
}
```

When I click on the addWidget button I want to add a Home Widget.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for adding an app widget this way. Users can add an app widget via the home screen.